# evaluate an arg when passing to a macro

Tags: clojure

I have a small macro which takes a series of cmds as clojure s expressions and returns their string representations. I am having trouble passing an argument to the macro -

```
(defmacro cmd [& cmds]
  (->> (for [v cmds]
         (join " " v))
       (join "; ")))

(defn install-jive [version]
  (cmd
   (yum remove jive-add-ons)
   (yum install jive-add-ons ~version)))

(install-jive 1.2)
```

I want the fn to return the following -

> (install-jive 1.2) => "yum remove jive-add-ons; yum install jive-add-ons 1.2"

However currently it returns -

> "yum remove jive-add-ons; yum install jive-add-ons
>   (clojure.core/unquote version)"

Comment: The problem is that macros are expanded (called) at definition time. when install-jive is defined you have ~version and not 1.2.

Comment: @cgrand what are my options ? How do I structure the macro to get access to the var ?

Comment: why a macro and not a function?

Comment: @Shlomi because I want to be able to write (yum install abc) - where none of these symbols are defined in the current ns. Is there an alternative ?

Comment: @murtaza52 you have to use an escape mechanism to tell what's static from what's dynamic. You can use the unquote form you accidently get as the escape mechanism. See my response for such an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about what **forms** you need your macro to generate. For example in your case you might want the macro to generate something like this after expansion:

```
(defn install-jive [version]
  (clojure.string/join
    ";"
    [(clojure.string/join " " (list "yum" "remove" "jive-add-ons"))
     (clojure.string/join " " (list "yum" "install" "jive-add-ons" version))]))
```

The macro transformed the first 3 elements on the list in a `String` and didn't touch `version`. Here is a macro that do that for one form:

```
(defmacro single-cmd [cmd-form]
  `(clojure.string/join " " (list ~@(map str (take 3 cmd-form))
                                  ~@(drop 3 cmd-form))))
```

Expanding this macro generates this:

```
(macroexpand '(single-cmd (yum remove jive-add-ons version)))
=> (clojure.string/join " " (clojure.core/list "yum" "remove" "jive-add-ons" version))

(macroexpand '(single-cmd (yum remove)))
=> (clojure.string/join " " (clojure.core/list "yum" "remove"))
```

Which is what we needed for each command to expand into. Now we need to create a macro that expands this:

```
(cmd
  (yum remove jive-add-ons)
  (yum install jive-add-ons version))
```

Into the form that we want. This is a simple version, just to give you the idea:

```
(defmacro cmd [& cmds]
  `(clojure.string/join
     ";"
     (list (single-cmd ~(first cmds))
           (single-cmd ~(second cmds)))))
```

Expanding it generates:

```
(macroexpand '(cmd
                (yum remove jive-add-ons)
                (yum install jive-add-ons version)))
=> (clojure.string/join 
     ";" 
     (clojure.core/list (user/single-cmd (yum remove jive-add-ons)) 
                        (user/single-cmd (yum install jive-add-ons version))))
```

And now:

```
(install-jive 1.2)
=> "yum remove jive-add-ons;yum install jive-add-ons 1.2"
```

My version makes two **big** assumptions: the first three elements should always be converted to `String` and you always call `cmd` with two, and only two, commands. You will probably need to improve that to solve your problem.

But I think this gives you a nudge in the right direction. There is a great book [Mastering Clojure Macros](https://pragprog.com/book/cjclojure/mastering-clojure-macros) that can help you develop your macros skills.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defmacro cmd [& cmds]
  `(join "; "
     [~@(for [cmd cmds]
         `(join " "
            [~@(for [arg cmd]
                 (if (and (seq? arg) (= (first arg) 'clojure.core/unquote))
                   (second arg)
                   (list 'quote arg)))]))]))
```

If you compare to the original code, you'll see that this one defers calls to join until runtime and turns unquote forms as expressions in the resulting command template.